# Django message framework rendered in a boostrap Modal

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-views

I have a Django App. And I would like to give a Welcome Message after the user signed in. I know how to do it using the framework message but the thing is I would like instead of rendering it within a div I would like to render it within a modal !

I tried :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       {% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But as you may imagine it does not work the modal does not render. 
Do you have any idea how could I make it work.

Actually it is more than a welcome message, it is a welcome and a small tutorial.

Thx you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Javascript or jQuery. You need it to activate the modal.

Use `show:true` or `show:false` based on your need.

Try to use :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#exampleModal').modal({show:true});
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps